# Toggle the button Image

Tags: ios, ios4, checkbox, uiimage

After i implemented a code for give an check image for a button but i want to give check image for no of buttons.

note: if i click on one button check image can be displayed and the same time i click on another button check image displayed on that particular button and previous button comes normal position.

i implement the code for single button here like this.

```
-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check 


{


_checked = check;


if( _checked )


{
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_check_on.png"];

[self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   }
    else

{

    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bread_Wheat_rectangle.png"];


    [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}


}
```

The above code is executed successfully but how to use this code for no of buttons.

please suggest any tutorial regarding my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long practicing this problem we can use switch cases it can be done very easily

```
switch (currenttagvalue) {
    case 1:
        [level1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one_time_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
        [level2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [level3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bread_sourdough_rectangle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
```

in this level is "IBOutlet UIButton level1;"

And then i implement so more buttons

Answer (score 3):

This is how I have implemented it for one button. You can use it for more buttons too.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction
{

    if (Flag==0) 
    {
        Flag=1;
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-filled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  

    }
    else
    {
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       Flag=0;

    }
}
```

**Note : If you want only one button to get checked Just set all other buttons image as checkbox.png and the selected one's checkbox-filled.png.**

**EDIT**

You can make a class for checkbox and then use it. Here is the code...

CheckButton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface CheckButton : UIButton {
    BOOL        _checked;
    int chkButtonClickVal;
}

@property (nonatomic, setter=setChecked:) BOOL checked;

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check;
-(int)chkButtonClickVal;
@end
```

CheckButton.m

```
#import "CheckButton.h"


@implementation CheckButton
@synthesize checked = _checked;

-(id) init
{
    if( self=[super init] )
    {
        chkButtonClickVal=0;
        self.checked = NO;
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.checked = NO;
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(OnCheck:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    chkButtonClickVal=0;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) setChecked:(BOOL) check 
{
    _checked = check;
    if( _checked )
    {
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        chkButtonClickVal=1;

    }
    else
    {
        UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];
        [self setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        chkButtonClickVal=2;
    }
    //NSLog(@"%d",chkButtonClickVal);
}

-(int)chkButtonClickVal
{
    return chkButtonClickVal;   
}

-(void) OnCheck:(id) sender
{
    self.checked = !_checked;
}

@end
```

I have done it in same way. Try you'll be able to achieve it. 
Good Luck :)

Comment: i tried but it is print duplicates. i mean if i click one button operation can be done to another button.if you have any tutorial please suggest for me.

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar Here is a very simple tutorial : http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-custom-checkboxes/ . Try that and let me know. I think it should work fine. :)

Comment: i tried one button it executes successfully  but i want to check no of buttons in a single view.my main aim is to click on one button display check image and click another button check image display on that button.

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar See my answer's EDIT Part. I have edited my answer. You'll get it.

Comment: hi friend i tried the above code but the problem is checked image can't displayed.

Comment: thank you friend it's working..........if my button is checked state .i click ok button.Display another view based on this checked condition database record.

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar Good that it worked for you. Happy to help. All the Best !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10176/discussion-between-medeti-naveen-kumar-and-learner)